# How can I relate a model instance to another in django?

Tags: python, django, django-models, database-relations

I'm trying to relate a model instance to another. For example, If I have a model named Person and I'd like to relate a person to his/her father. How can I do that?

I'm not proving a code because there isn't one about this specific question. But the example above is basically what I'm trying to do:

I have a model of people (named Voter) I'm trying to relate each instance to another as a relative (father, mother, sister)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: foreign key? well, if you didn't find any code about this, you didn't search well.
I'll give you a tip, it's a foreign key on self on your model person

Comment: Make sure you define the person relations(father, mother, etc.) field in the model and use foreign key referencing the same model for each person relations.

Comment: Downvoting for lack of effort; especially as there is no way you can have done the Django tutorial, which explicitly deals with relationships.

Comment: Hello and welcome to SO. You may want to read this : https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask. You'll notice that the very first advice in this page is "search" - something you very obviously forgot to do before posting.

Answer (score 1):

You can try this using a `ManytoManyField` within the model, that points to an instance of the same model. 
Any metadata about the relationship can be stored in its own "through" table.

```
class Person(models.Model):
    relation = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through=Relation)

class Relation(models.Model):
    relation1 = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    relation2 = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    type_of_relation = models.SmallPositiveIntegerField(choices=[(1,'Father'), (2, 'Sister')... etc])
```

Read more about Through tables and ManyToManyField here :
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/models/#extra-fields-on-many-to-many-relationships